# adding on ground traps with libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to look up how to add on ground traps in libGDX, but to no avail.  I would like to find a trap example.  It would be really nice if it uses object colisions, but I don't know if it is possible to do without making them impassable.

A use case would be like caltrops, where the player should be able to walk over them, but a collision still takes place.

Comment: You will have to provide a lot more details about your game (first-person shooter? platformer?) if you want a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of information is lacking on your question. But it seems you are using boxd2, because if you were handling the collisions with your custom code you would easily solve your problem.

If you are using boxd2, you can make your trap body a sensor.

```
body.getFixtureList().get(0).setSensor(true); //assuming it has only one fixture
```

And set its UserData to something you can check when the collision occurs.

```
body.getFixtureList().get(0).setUserData("trap");
```

then, define a contact listener to check for collisions with bodies with that user data:

```
//define the Contact listener
public class MyContactListener implements ContactListener{

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact){
        if ((String)contact.getFixtureA().getUserData()=="trap" || (String)contact.getFixtureB().getUserData()=="trap")
            //hurt player
    }

    @Override public void endContact(Contact contact){}
    @Override public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold){}
    @Override public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse){}
};
```

And create and set the contact listener in your ini code.

```
MyContactListener contactListener = new MyContactListener();
world.setContactListener(contactListener);
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond.  Life got crazy.